# How to get Facebook User ID that likes/comments a post of a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook page and i can get list of comments in a facebook page post using page access token. But i cannot get the facebook user id of that comment.
How can i archive that?

I already trying with

```
{comment-id}/comments?fields=message,from{id}
```

I'm using facebook graph API version 3.2

Regards,

Comment: i believe it´s not possible anymore for privacy reasons

Comment: is there any way to implements this? maybe we need app review from facebook first or something else?

Comment: app review can get you access to public pages you don´t own, but in that case it would not help. again, i believe it is not possible anymore for privacy reasons.

Comment: after trial, it can be done actually by changing my app status to live. I can get user id whose comments or like in my page post. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can send a private reply to the user and when that user will reply to that message then you can have the userId. Only this is the process which can provide you with userId.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/${commentId}/private_replies?access_token=${accessToken}
```

Comment: its resulting in error   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (private_replies) on node type (Comment)",
      "type": "OAuthException",

Comment: If your app has read_page_mailboxes permission then it will send a private reply. However, you can follow the following docs link for your clarity.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/object/private_replies